# Подскажите как подсчитать количество одинаковых значений в массиве?

Tags: php

Есть не совсем обычный массив, в котором есть такие значения:

```
$array = [
  '|3|7|',
  '|1|3|4|',
  '|2|3|',
  '|1|'
];
```

Нужно подсчитать количество одинаковых значений, и результат должен быть таким:

```
$array = [
  1 => 2,
  2 => 1,
  3 => 3,
  4 => 1,
  7 => 1
];
```

Будут только цифры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функцией `array_count_values`. Результат будет примерно таким

```
$array = [
  '|3|7|',
  '|1|3|4|',
  '|2|3|',
  '|1|'
];

$result = [] ;

foreach($array as $value) {
$result = Array_merge($result,explode('|', trim($value, '|')));
}
$result = array_count_values($result);
KSort($result) ; 
print_r ($result) ;
```